# Android Delete file from ListView and from a folder in storage

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I am trying to build an app that will Delete a file from a ListView 
and from a folder in storage, at the same time.

When I run this app a ListView displays the files in the folder.
A long click on a file in the ListView displays the Toast message 
but the Dialog Fails to display. The file is not removed from the 
ListView or the folder.

I would appreciate code help to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setLongClickable(true);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FileRemoveActivity.this);

            // this Title Fails to display
            alert.setTitle("Delete File");

            //  this Message Fails to display
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");

            // this Toast 'position' value Does display
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            alert.setCancelable(false);
            // the Yes button Fails to display
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // compiler warning this code is an Unchecked Cast
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) arg0.getAdapter();

                    // the file at 'position' is Not removed
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            });

            // the Cancel button Fails to display
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    }); // KJP NOTE: Test 07-May-2016 End Test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `alert.create(); alert.show();` at the end of the method before `return false;`.
Your dialog would be visible and then you can tap on `Yes` to remove the item.

Comment: Thanks Shadab Ansari. I added alert.create(); and alert.show();  immediately above return false;
Now the app will display the dialog. A long click on the OK button will remove the file from the listview but Not from the folder.
I run the app again and the file is still displayed in the listview.
Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: You have not written any code to remove the file from the folder.  How do you expect it to get deleted then ?

Comment: Per my post, I would appreciate code help to solve both task at the same time.

Comment: `File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();`
where `selectedFilePath` is the path of the file you want to delete.

Comment: Thank you. That code successfully removed the file from the folder.
Except that, on a long click the dialog is displayed (as it should be) but when I release the long click it propagates and causes a click event that displays a dialog over top of the long click dialog. How do I prevent this propagation?

Comment: Return `true` instead of `false`  from `onItemLongClick`. Accept the answer  if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just found that answer:

Comment: The answer: If your long-click method returns true then you are telling Android that you handled the event and nobody else should know about the long-press. If your method returns false, Android will still call other handlers such as your onItemClick handler. Long-press events in Android typically do not perform the same action as a regular press, so it may be best to return true to stop event propagation.

protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLongListItemClick id=" + id);
    return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you call alert.show() to actual show the dialog. You build it, but don't show it. There is an example of how this works [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/).